# How can disjoint columns be selected in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables each with different columns but they all have one column in common. This is an integer identifier column. So I will have some integer x, and I want all the rows from all 4 tables that have this one id column equal to x.

I've tried something similar to:

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=x OR coastlinessports.id=x
```

And I get back rows which have both the columns from both tables in the same row.

So one result block would have:

```
table1.col1, table2.col2
```

But I really want:

```
table1.col1
tale2.col2
```

Is there a way I can do this without doing 4 select queries in a row?

Comment: Can you post the structure of each table (the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`), and show exactly which columns you want from each?

Answer (score 2):

If you want sequential rows from different tables, and for each table to return a different number of rows, then you can use `UNION`.  However, `UNION` requires each `SELECT` to return the same number of columns, so you will need to fill in the missing columns with a value (or `NULL`), like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table2`;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `col1` VARCHAR(255),
  `col2` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `col1` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES
    (1, '1,1', '1,2'),
    (2, '2,1', '2,2');

INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES
    (1, '1,1'),
    (2, '2,1');

SELECT `id`, `col1`, `col2` FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = 1
UNION
SELECT `id`, `col1`, NULL AS `col2` FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = 1;

+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | 1,1  | 1,2  |
|  1 | 1,1  | NULL |
+----+------+------+
```

If you want to further process the `UNION` result set, you can wrap it in another `SELECT`, like this:

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM (
    SELECT `id`, `col1`, `col2` FROM `table1` WHERE `id` = 1
    UNION
    SELECT `id`, `col1`, NULL AS `col2` FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = 1
) AS `t1`
ORDER BY col2;

+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| 1,1  | NULL |
| 1,1  | 1,2  |
+------+------+
```

Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't answer your question, but there's something weird about the JOIN.

Usually the "ON" condition refers to both tables being joined, similar to this:

```
... FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id ...
```

I guess there can be cases where you wouldn't do that, but I can't think of any.

Comment: Better as a comment :-) Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is called the same you can use USING
And for the part of the given value, use WHERE

```
select * from table1 join table2 using(commonColumn) join table3 using(commonColumn) join table4 using(commonColumn) where commonColumn="desiredValue"
```

Update: on a second read of your question
You want this?

All rows of table1 where commonColumn="desiredValue"
Followed by
All rows of table2 where commonColumn="desiredValue"
Followed by
All rows of table3 where commonColumn="desiredValue"
Followed by
All rows of table4 where commonColumn="desiredValue"

If that's so, you need to use a UNION (and you have to make 4 selects)
IF the number of columns differs, you need to fill the gaps whit aliases

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1 where commonColumn="desiredValue"  
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, 0 as col3, 0 as col4 from table2 where commonColumn="desiredValue"  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this post. It seems like what you are asking for:
http://ask.sqlteam.com/questions/870/pivoting-multiple-rows-into-one-row-with-multiple-columns